# Is it possible to define a range for values of @PathVariable?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a method as following, {code} should only accept A,B or C.

I know that one way to solve it is to define three methods (one for each case) but thats is not an efficient way of doing this. Another approach is to use a single method that enclose a switch case, but is there any better approach to it?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "{code}/selection", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showSelectionOptions(@PathVariable String code){
  switch(code){
    case A:
    case B:
    case C:
       return "selection";
    default:
       return "error";
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You have a more direct solution for your need in Spring MVC. Try

```
@RequestMapping(value = "{code:A|B|C}/selection", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showSelectionOptions(@PathVariable String code){
   return "selection";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, how about if I would need to make that as a range, like A to Z

Comment: the above is simply a regular expression, so if you write a proper regex that suits your needs, you have your solution. I think that in your case it should be something like `{code:[A-Z]}` or something along that lines

Answer (score 2):

There is no more efficient method, since you need to make this check anyway. However, you can simplify your life, for instance by creating an `enum` with the approved values, like this:

```
public enum Numbers {
    ONE("Uno "),
    TWO("Dos "),
    THREE("Tres ");
}
```

You can traverse it like this:

```
for (Numbers dir : Numbers.values()) {
  // do what you want
}
```

and you can implement a method, like this

```
public String showSelectionOptions(@PathVariable String code){
    return Arrays.asList(Numbers.values()).contains(code) ? "selection" : "error";
}
```

This is not more efficient, but it is a shorter code which helps if you have many values to work with.

Answer (score 2):

All answers are kind of fine. But they are missing an important piece of information:

You can also use other object types instead of String in requestmappings.

In your case an enum with A, B and C would exactly do that job.

```
@RequestMapping(value="{code}/...")
public String do(@PathVariable("code") MyEnum code) {...}
```

- typesafe
- automatic mapping
- restricted to possible enum values
- no manual testing

Comment: do as a function name is not allowed :)

Comment: Hi, could you add an enum example too please?  Does Spring MVC take the enum value as String to compare with the parameter?

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach looks fine. My only suggestion is if you do not want to pass the {code} as a URL parameter but as part of request body then you can use `@RequestBody` instead of `@PathVariable` and map the request body to a DTO class. you can use `@validated` to validate that atleast one value to {code} ir provided.

But having said that i do not see anything wrong with your approach.